# Is there any Android equivalent of iOS UIAccessibilityTraits?

Tags: android, button, layout, accessibility

In my Android app I have a custom layout that is being used as a button - it consists of some `TextViews` and an `ImageView`, additionally it has some gradient background.

I'm aligning my app now to conform to the Accessibility rules. In order to do so, I would need to convert this layout into a button, so that TalkBack can correctly indicate the action, that this whole layout is clickable and serves like a button.

I know that on iOS there is a possibility to set the [`UIAccessibilityTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620194-button) to treat such view as a button - this kind of solution would save me a huge amount of work in terms of migration.

Is there any similar solution on Android for that? What approach should I follow in order to make this layout recognized correctly by TalkBack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no concept of accessibility traits on Android - but you can still get a good accessibility experience without needing to specifically convert your layout into a `Button`.

Generally, it's most important that TalkBack (or whatever accessibility service is being used - remember, it's not just TalkBack) is able to detect that the widget is clickable and to be able to read a coherent description of what it does.  The additional information that it's a button, specifically, isn't super useful, especially because there are so many different kinds of UI elements that it's often a very ambiguous question whether something even *is* a button.

You can test this by selecting it in TalkBack and confirming that it reads the content description properly, says something along the lines of "Double tap to activate," and performs the correct action when you double tap.

If it's not correct, make sure the [content description](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)), [clickable flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat#setClickable(boolean)), and [click action](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat#ACTION_CLICK) are set correctly on the widget's AccessibilityNodeInfo.

Comment: This is what I actually suspected, just needed some other pair of the eyes on this topic. Thanks for your input!